# i am trying to understand how formal parameters work in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, trying to understand what formal parameters are. I am reading this book called "the complete c++ reference", there is an example provided in the book about formal parameters which I am attaching in the code below. when I try to execute the program a list of errors is being displayed can anyone explain where I am going wrong.

Code from book

```
/* Return 1 if c is part of string s; 0 otherwise */
int is_in(char *s, char c) {
  while(*s)
    if (*s==c)
      return 1;
    else
      s++;
  return 0;
}
```

Program which I am trying to execute

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int is_in(char* s, char c){
  while(s)
    if(s==c)
      return 1;
    else
       s++;
  return 0;
};

char* s = (char*)"flying";
char c;

int main(void){      
  is_in(s, 'g');
}
```

Comment: A `formal` parameter is the parameter you write when you declare  the method or function. I.e. it defines what types the function/method takes and how many.
An `actual` parameter is the parameter you use when you `call` the function. i.e it is a variable or constant you put into the function.

In your case, `char* s, char c` (in line 5) are formal parameters and `s, 'g'` (within `main`) are actual parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is at

```
 while(s)
    if(s==c)return 1;
```

s is a char pointer, in order to get the value stored at the memory to which the pointer s is pointing, you must de-reference it by using a * operator as shown in the example

```
    while(*s)
       if(*s==c) return 1;
```

```
#include <iostream>

int
is_in(char * s, char c) {
  while ( * s)
    if ( * s == c)
      return 1;
    else
      s++;
  return 0;
};

char * s = (char * )
"flyin";

char c;

int
main(void) {
  is_in(s, 'g');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: now the program is running successfully, but the end result is concerning Program ended with exit code: 0

the end result is expected with exit code as 1. Because char c is present in string s

Comment: yeah, that's the return 0 in the main function. it means it has executed successfully with no issues. in cause you want to see the result of is_in() function call, you can print it out using cout i.e `cout << is_in(s, 'g');`